# How do I access my phone's accelerometer and gyroscope in Python?

Tags: python, android, kivy, accelerometer, gyroscope

My question is, is there a way to access my Android phone's accelerometer and gyroscope data? Basically, I want to get the data with a python mobile app made in Kivy, send it via sockets to my pc and do stuff with it.

The sockets bit I have got the hang of and Kivy I am learning, it's just extracting the accelerometer and gyroscope data that I need help with.

Is there a module or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use plyer package https://github.com/kivy/plyer

Answer (score 0):

This other question helped me.
[How to transmit Android real-time sensor data to computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245849/how-to-transmit-android-real-time-sensor-data-to-computer)

I started using this Android app "Sensor Stream"
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sensorsensei

And this Python server "Sensor Stream Server"
https://github.com/priyankark/SensorStreamServer